# Are there ISO 19131 compliant spatial dataset specifications?

Tags: standards

[ISO 19131](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=36760) is a standard for spatial dataset specifications (the way a dataset is created and supplied).

Do you know examples of specification documents (possibly available online) compliant with this standard?

(I am aware this is not a very exciting question, but I need it!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [INSPIRE data specifications documents](http://inspire.jrc.ec.europa.eu/index.cfm/pageid/2),
- Some databases produced by [eurogeographics](http://www.eurogeographics.org) (like [euroBoundaryMap](http://www.ign.es/ign/resources/actividades/proyint/EuroBoundaryMap_v40_Specification.pdf) and [RISE](http://www.eurogeographics.org/documents/RISE25DataProductSpecificationsV1.0.pdf)),
- and [an example](http://www.freegis-italia.org/index.php?option=com_docman&task=doc_download&gid=42) is given in annex of the ISO itself

Comment: Do you think the example provided into the annex is real or unreal? I think is real. why don't you contact the Canadian organism itself? if other implementations exit, they should be aware

Comment: I agree it is certainly a real. Yes, I could contact them.

Answer (score 0):

All below are implemented by INSPIRE

Geographic information Metadata:

ISO:19115: http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=26020

ISO 19115-2:2009
http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=39229

And for Geographic information Services:

ISO 19119:2005

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am not looking for ISO standards implemented in INSPIRE but existing documents based on ISO 19131.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant?

[see section 2.6 of this document](http://www.eurogeographics.org/documents/Guidelines_ISO19100_Quality.pdf)

I see the other sites want money for the documentation.  I'm not sure if this is what you're after.  Hope it helps.

**EDIT**: ok .... try this link [ISO Concept Database](https://cdb.iso.org/cdb/search.action)

You can select one of the tabs accross the top and view some of the standards for symbology, etc.  If you look at my printscreen, I went under the "*graphical symbols*" tab, then I selected "*transport facilities*" and hit the search button.  If you fish around in here, you might at least get a sense of what you're dealing with and be able to get a feel for the standards.  Is this closer to what you were after?  I think I'm out of ideas!  I hope this at least puts you on the right track to answering your question.

[image: ISO Symbology Standards]

Comment: It is not exactly what I am looking for (I am looking for examples of documents that implement the ISO 19131). Anyway, it is a very good document! +1

Comment: I do believe .... you may have to pay for what you're after.  Looks that way to me anyway.

Comment: Thanks, but what I am looking for are examples of documents that implement the ISO 19131.